# Am I right in removing the [symbolism] tag from this question?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question

This is the question https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/14801/who-is-lucas-akimoto and the [revision history](https://anime.stackexchange.com/posts/14801/revisions).

I'm not sure if the removal of [symbolism](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symbolism) is correct.

The question is asking *whether a character in the anime is a reference to something*, which I think is ill-fit for the description of the tag (emphasis mine):

> This tag is for questions looking for **meanings**, either explicit or subject to interpretation, behind a character, a setting, an action of a character, a plot point.

What do you guys think?

Comment: I believe removing it is correct. Questions about characters should fall within the general scope of a series tag. The series tag takes precedence before anything, if applicable. The Soul Eater question doesn't need it per say as it i asking about a specific reference. Take a look at [this meta](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/929/somebody-please-clarify-the-symbolism-tag-wiki) if you wish to discuss specifics of the tag.

Comment: I've thought for a while that [tag:symbolism] is too vague and broad to be a good tag. On the other hand, [the last time](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/896/should-we-get-rid-of-the-symbolism-tag) we debated this on meta, there was no consensus. At the very least, I think you should be safe removing it if the question clearly has little to do with symbolism. In this case, the OP is asking about a possible reference, which is rather different IMO. So, in short, I agree with your interpretation.